# Rails - Find records with only one specific associated has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering how to find records with only one specific `has_and_belongs_to_many` item.

The associations are as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

The following is what I normally use.

```
User.includes(:roles).where(roles: {name: 'guest'})
```

This is not sufficient because I want to find all users with only the role `guest`. It should not get records that have any other roles in addition to `guest`.

Can someone show me the way here? Ideally the solution would be compatible with all SQL database types (mysql, mariadb, postgres, sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.includes(:roles).where(roles: {name: 'guest'}).having("COUNT(roles.id)=1")
```

I also would recommend to use `joins`instead of `includes` if you don't need to eager load the query.